# Postgres : using computed variable in a SELECT statement part 1/2

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a SELECT statement as follow (doesn't work):

```sql
SELECT 
    extract(day from CAST (date as TIMESTAMP) - CAST (birth_date as TIMESTAMP)) / 365.25 as age_norm,
    CASE 
       WHEN age_norm >= 0 AND age_norm <1 THEN '00'
       WHEN age_norm >= 1 AND age_norm <5 THEN '01-4'
       --etc
    END as age_group
FROM foo
```

Is there a way to "inject" here the "variable" `age_norm`in the query ?

EDIT:

Asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72699395/postgres-using-computed-variable-in-a-select-statement-part-2-2), but this time with an additional column in the `SELECT` statement, which is the use case I'm trying to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can calculate the `age_norm` column in a subquery and then use `age_norm` by `CASE WHEN` in the main query.

```
SELECT 
    age_norm,
    CASE 
       WHEN age_norm >= 0 AND age_norm <1 THEN '00'
       WHEN age_norm >= 1 AND age_norm <5 THEN '01-4'
       --etc
    END as age_group
FROM (
   SELECT extract(day from CAST (date as TIMESTAMP) - CAST (birth_date as TIMESTAMP)) / 365.25 as age_norm
   FROM foo
) t1
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Refined the question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72699395/postgres-using-computed-variable-in-a-select-statement-part-2-2), as I have another column in the select statement as mentionned in the edit of the initial post.