# Postgres : using computed variable in a SELECT statement (part 2/2)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a SELECT statement as follow (doesn't work):

```sql
SELECT foo,
    extract(day from CAST (date as TIMESTAMP) - CAST (birth_date as TIMESTAMP)) / 365.25 as age_norm,
    CASE 
       WHEN age_norm >= 0 AND age_norm <1 THEN '00'
       WHEN age_norm >= 1 AND age_norm <5 THEN '01-4'
       --etc
    END as age_group
FROM bar
```

Is there a way to "inject" here the "variable" `age_norm`in the query ?

**NOTE**

Asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72699035/postgres-using-computed-variable-in-a-select-statement), but without the parameter `foo`present in this question

**EDIT**

Tried:

```sql
SELECT foo,
    (
    SELECT t.age_norm,
    CASE 
       WHEN t.age_norm >= 0 AND t.age_norm <1 THEN '00'
       WHEN t.age_norm >= 1 AND t.age_norm <5 THEN '01-4'
       --etc
    END 
    FROM (SELECT extract(day from CAST (date as TIMESTAMP) - CAST (birth_date as TIMESTAMP)) / 365.25 as age_norm FROM bar) t
    )
   as age_group
FROM bar
```

But getting:

```
ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
LINE 10:     (  SELECT t.age_norm,
             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 212
```

**CONCLUSION**

Tried some of proposed solutions but either the resulting query is too slow (compared to hard coding the extract function in each where clause) or the resulting query become too complicate (it is in fact more complicate than expressed in this post with group by clauses and others things).

So will implements each when clause as follow:

```sql
WHEN (extract(day from CAST (date as TIMESTAMP) - CAST (birth_date as TIMESTAMP)) / 365.25) >=0 AND (extract(day from CAST (date as TIMESTAMP) - CAST (birth_date as TIMESTAMP)) / 365.25) <1 THEN '00' 
etc.
```

Thank you for your replies!

Comment: doesn't work?  what do you want it to do?

Comment: Edited the question. I'd like to be able to calculate `age_norm`so it can be reused in the WHEN clauses

Comment: Ah. you probably want a lateral join or a CTE instead of a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Use a derived table (a query in the FROM clause):

```sql
SELECT 
    foo,
    age_norm,
    CASE 
       WHEN age_norm >= 0 AND age_norm <1 THEN '00'
       WHEN age_norm >= 1 AND age_norm <5 THEN '01-4'
    END as age_group
FROM (
    SELECT 
        foo,
        extract(day from CAST (date as TIMESTAMP) - CAST (birth_date as TIMESTAMP)) / 365.25 as age_norm
    FROM bar
    ) s
```

Comment: Wanted to try but my overall query is quite big, with group by clause and surrounding clause (with data) and guessing it will, in my case the resulting query might be over complicate. Up voted as it work through. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

perhaps a lateral join like this....

```
SELECT foo,age_group.*
FROM 
FROM bar
, LATERAL (
   SELECT t.age_norm,
   CASE 
      WHEN t.age_norm >= 0 AND t.age_norm <1 THEN '00'
      WHEN t.age_norm >= 1 AND t.age_norm <5 THEN '01-4'
      --etc
   END 
    FROM (SELECT extract(day from CAST (bar.date as TIMESTAMP) - CAST bar.birth_date as TIMESTAMP)) / 365.25 as age_norm ) t
) as age_group;
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work but it is very slow so I interrupted it. Hard coding the calculation in each WHEN clause sounds the fastest. Thanks again for your reply